# How to post data and download the csv file using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, export-to-csv

I am posting control values as parameters and then trying to download the data in CSV format the code is as follows

```
function ExportToExcel(pageNumber, isPagination) {
                    var gcModel = {
                        Fromdate: $('#dateFrom').val(),
                        Todate: $('#dateTo').val(),
                        FromStore: $('#FromStore').val(),
                        ToStore: $('#ToStore').val(),
                        };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/GiftCard/ExportToExcel",
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(gcModel),
                        // data: { },
                        success: function (responce) {

                        },
                        error: function () {

                        }

                    })
                }
```

Here the data is getting posted to the method as parameters and the function is working fine but No CSV is getting downloaded , What I have to do to get the data downloaded as CSV by Posting those values, Kindly Help I am new to this, cant use form as there are other functions getting disturbed, Kindly suggest me the solution this is all over my head now, Thanks!!